# How do i upload multiple images in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have seen how to upload multiple images or files in octobercms but it has not worked for me yet.

i have tried with adding [] to the name attribute like name='images[]'but it only uploads the last image

My code currently in `PostForm.php`

```php
$advert->allimage = Input::file('allimage');
```

while `default.htm` is

```html
<div >
  <input type="file" name="allimage[]" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" >
  <label  >Choose file</label>
</div>
```

I even added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form but no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach (Input::file('allimage') as $file) {
    $advert->allimage()->create(['data' => $file]);
}
```

But make sure that you have defined `attachMany` relation in your Advert model:

```
public $attachMany = [
    'allimage' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

See more info [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments).

Or just try to save your model:

```
$advert->allimage = Input::file('allimage');
$advert->save();
```